# Using array generate header as a key and value as a data for generate excel file using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, excel

I am go wanna generate excel file from the array. and i am getting success for he generate excel file. but here i am getting not propare set header and data in raw. i am write some code here in javascript but no getting propare data. so any one how can do that then please let me know. here below i have pasted my array.

This is my array =>

```
var xlsx = require('node-xlsx');.
var  FinalFilterArray= [];
FinalFilterArray.push({ fullName: 'love',
        username: 'lo.ve632',
        biography: '',
        externalUrl: '',
        followerCount: 10,
        followingCount: 107,
       mediaCount: 0 },
     { fullName: 'abc',
       username: '@bc',
       biography: '',
       externalUrl: '',
       followerCount: 288,
       followingCount: 261,
       mediaCount: 0 },
    { fullName: 'xyz',
      username: 'xyz',
      biography: '#This is my ',
     externalUrl: '',
     followerCount: 234,
      followingCount: 282,
     mediaCount: 17 })
```

I have write like this code =>

```
 var header = [];
    var values = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < FinalFilterArray.length; i++) {
        if (i==0) {
            header.push("fullName", "username", "biography", "externalUrl", "followerCount", "followingCount", "mediaCount")
        }
        values[i] = [ FinalFilterArray[i].fullName, FinalFilterArray[i].username, FinalFilterArray[i].biography, FinalFilterArray[i].externalUrl, FinalFilterArray[i].followerCount, FinalFilterArray[i].followingCount, FinalFilterArray[i].mediaCount]
    }
    const data = [header, values]
    var buffer = xlsx.build([{ name: "mySheetName", data: data }]);
```

using this code i am geting like this data in excel file =>

```
fullName                 | username           | biography           |externalUrl    followerCount   followingCount  mediaCount  
love,lo.ve632,,,10,107,0 | abc,@bc,,,288,261,0 | xyz,xyz,,234,282,17|
```

My expected o/p =>

```
fullName   | username     | biography             |externalUrl |followerCount | followingCount |    mediaCount  
 love       | lo.ve632     |                       |            | 10           | 107            |    0
 abc        | @bc          |                       |            | 288          | 261            |    0
 xyz       | xyz          |#This is my            |            | 234           | 282            |    17
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `header.push` function instead of `values[i]` variable, like:

```
header.push(FinalFilterArray[i].fullName,
    FinalFilterArray[i].username,
    FinalFilterArray[i].biography,
    FinalFilterArray[i].externalUrl, 
    FinalFilterArray[i].followerCount, 
    FinalFilterArray[i].followingCount, 
    FinalFilterArray[i].mediaCount)
```

and also change

```
const data = [header]
```